# Flutter : how to convert latitude and longitude to live location address in flutter from firebase

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, cross-platform

I want to convert latitude and longitude in flutter to current address while address is change dynamic while phone is move from place to place to show it in app from firebase database .. what is the solution of it? .. I hope any one have a solution for me

Note l is latitude and longitude of availableDrivers in firebase database

```
-availableDrivers
  -3gDKSbnMEBYZsZDwL6lmiQerP9P2
    -g: "stq4cdrekx"
    -l
     0: 30.0276054
     1: 31.0139209
```

class DriversItem

```
import 'package:drivers_app/Data_Handler/app_Data.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/config_maps.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class DriversItem extends StatelessWidget
{

  final DataSnapshot? dataSnapshot;
  final int? index;

  const DriversItem({required this.dataSnapshot, required this.index});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
      child: Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        elevation: 10.0,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          height: 120.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children:
              [
                Text(
                  "Location : ${dataSnapshot!.value["l"]}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                Text(
                  "Address : ${Provider.of<AppData>(context, listen: false).myAddress.placeName != null ?  Provider.of<AppData>(context).myAddress.placeName : 'No Address found'}",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

class Zones

```
import 'package:drivers_app/Assistants/assistantMethods.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/Data_Handler/app_Data.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/config_maps.dart';
import 'package:drivers_app/shared/components/drivers_item.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../main.dart';

class ZonesScreen extends StatefulWidget
{

  @override
  State<ZonesScreen> createState() => _ZonesScreenState();
}

class _ZonesScreenState extends State<ZonesScreen> {

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    locatePosition(context);
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 15.0,
              ),
              Text(
                  "Available Drivers",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
              FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: availableDriverRef,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, snapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index,)
                => DriversItem(index: index, dataSnapshot: snapshot,),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void locatePosition(context) async
  {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    String Address = await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position, context);
  }


}
```

class Address model

```
class Address{
  String? placeFormatedAddress;
  String? placeName;
  String? placeId;
  double latitude = 0.0;
  double longitude = 0.0;

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the `geocoding` package already - Does `placemarkFromCoordinates(lat, long)` give you the info you need? https://pub.dev/documentation/geocoding/latest/geocoding/placemarkFromCoordinates.html

Comment: @MichaelHorn Can you tell me how i can use this package in my code to give my the live address and change dynamic when phone is change from place to another